# How to add current class to specific categories using php

Tags: php, pligg

I want to add class *current* for every li when it is active using php (I am absolutely new with it). I have the following code:

```
<ul id="frumos">
    <li {if $pagename eq "upcoming"} class="current" {/if}><a href="/upcoming.php?category=economic">Economic</a></li>  
   <li {if $pagename eq "/upcoming.php?category=other"} *(this doesn't work)* class="current" {/if}><a href="/upcoming.php?category=other">Freestyle</a></li>

   <li><a href="/upcoming.php?category=social">Social</a></li>
</ul>
```

If i use `{if $pagename eq "upcoming"}` it works fine but if I put `{if $pagename eq "/upcoming.php?category=other"}` it doesn't work what structure should I use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?PHP
$category = $_REQUEST[category];

echo "<ul id='frumos'>";
    echo "<li ";
    if($category == 'economic'){
        echo " class='current'";
    }
    echo "><a href='/upcoming.php?category=economic'>Economic</a></li> ";
    echo "<li";
    if($category == 'other'){
        echo " class='current'";
    }
    echo "><a href='/upcoming.php?category=other'>Freestyle</a></li>";
    echo "<li";
    if($category == 'social'){
        echo " class='current'";
    }
    echo "><a href='/upcoming.php?category=social'>Social</a></li>";
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much I have been playing with it for 4 hours already you saved me a lot of time !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cleanest way to butcher your html is with a turinary.  Essentially it is a compact if else statment.

```
<li <?php echo ($pagename === "/upcoming.php?category=other") ? echo 'class="current"' : ''; ?> >
```